# how to get checked value from two url simultaneousl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I have two buttons one for Groups and second is for Skills. when i click on groups button one popup will show and in the popup the groups are showing with checkbox. wheni select the groups and click on save button the checked groups will show on the uper of group button and popup will close.and this same is for skills button also.

My problem is that when i select groups it will show on groups button but when i select skill i lost the selected groups.

**right now i am doing this:**

```
 function OnClickButton () {

        var display = "";
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("group");
        for( var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
            if( checkboxes[i].checked ){
                display += " " + checkboxes[i].value;
            }
        }

        window.location.href='job_posting.html?data='+display;
    }

    <button type="button"   onclick="OnClickButton()"  >Save</button>
```

**this is for Groups.**

```
function OnClickButton1 () {

    var display1 = "";
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("skill");
    for( var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
        if( checkboxes[i].checked ){
            display1 += " " + checkboxes[i].value;
        }
    }

    window.location.href='job_posting.html?data='+display1;
}
<button type="button"   onclick="OnClickButton1()"  >Save</button>
```

And this is for skills.

I get the groups and skills in the url .Not for get the url i try this

```
function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode){
var currLocation = (staticURL.length)? staticURL : window.location.search,
       parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
       returnBool = true;

   for(var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++){
        parr = parArr[i].split("=");
        if(parr[0] == parameter){
            return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
            returnBool = true;
        }else{
            returnBool = "";            
        }
   }   

   if(!returnBool) return false;  
}


function get_data()
{
var idParameter = getUrlParameters("data","",true);
var idParameter1 = getUrlParameters("data1","",true);

document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=idParameter;
document.getElementById('display1').innerHTML=idParameter1;

}
```

Call this on

```
<body onLoad="get_data();">
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something similar to the following

```
function handleRedirect() {
    var url = 'job_posting.html?data=';
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('name');
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
            url += checkboxes[i].value + " ";
        }           
    }
    url += '&data1=';
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('skill');
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
            url += checkboxes[i].value + " ";
        }           
    }

    window.location.href = url;
}


<button type="button" onclick="handleRedirect()"  >Save</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="handleRedirect()"  >Save</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But There is one problem in this..when i select groups the grous are showing but whent i select skill then selected groups are losting.

Comment: You'll want to loop through all the url parameters, split them on spaces and then find all the associated checkboxes and check those.

Comment: can you explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

Victor is right, that is the way I would do it too in raw JS, only with one difference:

```
<button type="button" onclick="OnNameSaveClicked()"  >Save</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="OnSkillSaveClicked()"  >Save</button>
```

As you can see it does the same thing so you can do:

```
<button type="button" onclick="handleRedirect()"  >Save</button>
```

And you would have the same effect with a fewer lines of code.